# List vs ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Часто встречаю в книгах: необходим `ArrayList`. но вместо

```
ArrayList<> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

Делают так:

```
List<> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

В чём плюс этого?

Comment: @iksuy не. Тут скорее ООП: про использование базовых типов vs использование конкретных типов.

Comment: @andreycha, всё равно есть)

Comment: @Qwertiy ну вот это другое дело.

Answer (score 2):

Это делает код более гибким и позволяет проще подменить конкретную реализацию списка в случае необходимости. Предпоследняя буква в [SOL**I**D](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) про это в частности.