# List, Arraylist, инициализация

Tags: java, list, коллекции, arraylist

Часто начал замечать, что пишут вот такую конструкцию:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Зачем?
Почему не используют вот такую и какая разница? Я вроде ничего не заметил.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709670/list-vs-arraylist

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513092/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba

Comment: Для локально создаваемых переменных это сугубо вопрос предпочтений